# How to mock (simulate) MyBatis-Plus data access layer for unit testing for Model<> Active Record?

Tags: java, mybatis

In codebase where model classes use Model from https://github.com/baomidou/mybatis-plus

```
public class SomeDomainClass extends Model<SomeDomainClass> {
```

How to mock (simulate) MyBatis-Plus data access layer for unit testing?

---

Longer code example

```java
package com.company.project.domain;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.*;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.extension.activerecord.Model;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.experimental.Accessors;
import lombok.experimental.Tolerate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Accessors(chain = true)
@TableName("t_order")
@Builder
public class Order extends Model<Order> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ApiModelProperty(name = "id" , value = "id")
    @TableId(value = "f_id", type = IdType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ApiModelProperty(name = "orderId" , value = "orderId")
    private Long orderId;
```

Comment: Past your code here

Comment: added longer example, it helps to see exact imports

Comment: I like the idea of mocking persistence, though I really don't like the concept of "active record". Still +1